# Display rows and columns based on javascript array data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I could dynamically display columns and rows based on the target amount.

Let me clarify this more clearly.
I have a javascript array called `groepsCodes`. 
I want to make a bootstrap column for each of these group codes.

The problem is that I only want four columns per row, so if I have 5 group codes I would like 4 columns in one row and 1 column in the next row. 
More ideally would be 3 columns & 2 columns, but that's an issue for later. 
I feel like this is the point where my javascript knowledge stops, so if anyone knows what to do, I'd be glad to hear it.

**Edit:**

As suggested I should add code.

In my HTML I have these divs that need to be filled:

```
   <div id="groupCharts">
        <div class="row" id="groupChartsRow">
        </div>
    </div>
```

In javascript I do that as such:

```
    groepsCodes = ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3"];
for (i = 0; i < groepsCodes.length; i++) {
    $("#groupChartsRow").append("<div class='col'><div class='chartCard'>Hoi</div></div><br>");
}
```

Now this works fine. But let's say `groepsCodes` has 5 items instead of 4. 
Now I'd like an extra row div, how could I solve this?

Comment: You're right, I've added code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you want to add a new row every fourth item.

So instead of append it right away, build your HTML first and then append. You can use % to check if the fourth item has passed.

```js
var groepsCodes = ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"];
var html = '<div class="row">';

for (i = 0; i < groepsCodes.length; i++) {
   if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0) {
    html += '</div>'
    html += '<div class="row">'
   }
   html += '<div class="col"><div class="chartCard">Hoi</div></div><br>'
}

$('#result').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I was too late and didn't know you used Bootstrap

Comment: No this does exactly what I need it to do, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

That's `Grid System` in Bootstrap can do for you

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

when you specify `col-3` that' mean `12 / 3` so it will be `4` per row if you're using Bootstrap 4

if you're using Bootstrap 3 use `col-xs-3`

---

**Working Example**
*css for demo only*

```js
let groepsCodes = ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test5", ];

for (i = 0; i < groepsCodes.length; i++) {
  $("#groupChartsRow").append("<div class='col-3'><div class='chartCard'>Hoi</div></div><br>");
}
```

```css
[class^="col"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div id="groupCharts">
  <div class="row" id="groupChartsRow">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works, thank you.
However, I don't want every item to be col-3. If a row contains only 1 item, I would like it to be regular col (col-12), if it would contain 2 items I would like it to be col-6. That's why I used col, this automatically fils a row with the amount of columns it has (up to 12)

Comment: Welcome, in your code you use `col` only that will be one row with all columns